# ESXI autostart order not keeping from cold reboot?

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have tried setting the autostart of my vm's from the VM main screen like so however after doing a Cold Reboot through IDrac and coming back to this menu, the Auto Start Order was all unset again and nothing started.
[image]

Second attempt I went to Host->Manage->Autostart and set them like this -

[image]

and did another IDRAC cold reboot and this to seemed to disappear after.  I waited 20 minutes logged on and no VM was started and everything was back to unset.

I must be missing something obvious or some setting.  Can someone help me out with why this VM Autostart ordering is not keeping through the reboots/starting the VM's as expected?

Comment: If you are running a High Availability [HA] cluster in VMware, then I do not believe this will work.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle The two server's don't use vCenter if that matters.  They're plain ESXI 7.0.2 operating systems.  Any failover would be done manually in this setup.  Is there a way I could check if they are set to high availability?  I can't seem to find that in the ESXI Web UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very minor thing I missed but may as well post it for posterity sake.

In addition to configuring any one particular VM I also had to set the Autostart enabled in general here -
[image]

Doing that does make my VM at least attempt to start when ESXI is turned on.